# a warning of type 'error' while in the json snippet below we see `"success": 1`

Tags: wikibase

On our [wikibase server](https://api.kunstmuseum.nl/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=abc&language=en) we see a cryptic message, a warning of type 'error' while in the json snippet below we see `"success": 1`

```
Warning: {"type":"error","message":"cirrussearch-backend-error","params":[]} [Called from Wikibase\Search\Elastic\EntitySearchElastic::getRankedSearchResults in /var/www/html/extensions/WikibaseCirrusSearch/src/EntitySearchElastic.php at line 318] in /var/www/html/includes/debug/MWDebug.php on line 333
```

```
{
    "searchinfo": {
        "search": "abc"
    },
    "search": [],
    "success": 1
}
```

http://api.kunstmuseum.nl/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=abc&language=en

Comment: This seems to be https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T260276 but we're running the latest container setup from https://github.com/wmde/wikibase-docker/ already. We have previous SSL struggles described on https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T260328

Answer (score 1):

The [CirrusSearch README](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/g/mediawiki/extensions/CirrusSearch/+/HEAD/README) mentioned some steps that seem to have helped:

```
Now run this script to generate your elasticsearch index:
 php $MW_INSTALL_PATH/extensions/CirrusSearch/maintenance/UpdateSearchIndexConfig.php
Now remove $wgDisableSearchUpdate = true from LocalSettings.php.  Updates should start heading to Elasticsearch.
Next bootstrap the search index by running:
 php $MW_INSTALL_PATH/extensions/CirrusSearch/maintenance/ForceSearchIndex.php --skipLinks --indexOnSkip
 php $MW_INSTALL_PATH/extensions/CirrusSearch/maintenance/ForceSearchIndex.php --skipParse
Note that this can take some time.  For large wikis read "Bootstrapping large wikis" below.
```